# Are this way session data safer?

Tags: php, session

If I set cookies like this:

```
$_SESSION[md5('ponies'.$salt)] = $value;
```

so that only knowing the correct key will let you open that data, for example

```
$data = $_SESSION[md5('ponies'.$salt)];
```

and adding possibly a salt, will make my sessions data safer?

Comment: md5 isn't very safe, it doesn't matter if you add an salt (there exist many rainbow tables, ...). But: why do you need this?? If someone can execute a script on your server, he will most likely get the key and salt, too.

Comment: @user1150525, If someone can execute a script on my server, my last thought would go to session data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You're still setting the values with a static key, so it's pretty easy to just copy the key/value combination to a different client. You can also easily break normal MD5 hashing with rainbow tables. cookie keys are not serialized or secret, they are stored and accessible as stings in the `key=value` style on the client side.

Comment: yup. It's like just saying banana when you mean apple, people will catch up with what you are talking about by applying the context.